# Django-allauth - Custom Sign Up with OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth

I created a [sign up form using two grouped forms](https://youtu.be/Tja4I_rgspI) and it has been working perfectly, but I would like to use django-allauth because of the features (login only with e-mail, sending confirmation e-mail ...).
However even reading some topics I still couldn't.

**forms.py**

```
class ExtendedUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label="E-mail")
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Nome")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Sobrenome")


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)

        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('sexo', 'data_nascimento', 'foto', 'sobre_mim', 'telefone', 'paroquia',
                  'cidade','estado', 'cep', 'possui_filhos', 'facebook', 'instagram')
        CIDADES = []
        for i in cidadesReader:
            if i[1] not in CIDADES:
                CIDADES.append(i[1])
        widgets = {            
            'cidade': floppyforms.widgets.Input(datalist=CIDADES, attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'}),            
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExtendedUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = form.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user


            profile.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            #login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ExtendedUserCreationForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'profile_form' : profile_form}
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', context)
```

**signup.html**

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Cadastrar{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<h2>Criar Perfil</h2>
<form novalidate method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    {{ profile_form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    
    
        SEXOS = (
            ('M', 'Masculino'),
            ('F', 'Feminino'),
        )
        sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEXOS)
        data_nascimento = models.DateField(validators=[idade_minima])    
        ...
```

I've tried using the **ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS** and **ACCOUNT_FORMS** options in **settings.py**, but it didn't work.

I tried to make some adjustments, as in this topic similar to my question:
[Django allauth saving custom user profile fields with signup form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565927/django-allauth-saving-custom-user-profile-fields-with-signup-form)

For example, I changed it in **models.py** and I did **migrate**:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True, related_name ='profile')
```

After several attempts, the most common error is:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/signup/

User has no profile.
```

**Edit:**

I changed my slug in UserProfile, because it depends from user (first name). The error changed:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/

NOT NULL constraint failed: profiles_userprofile.user_id
```

But **UserProfile has no user** continues in the final.
(Using in **settings.py**: `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'profiles.forms.UserProfileForm'`. Details from traceback:

```
...lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py in dispatch
215 return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py in post
104 response = self.form_valid(form)

...lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py in form_valid
231 self.user = form.save(self.request)

...lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py in save
405 self.custom_signup(request, user)

...lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py in custom_signup
359 custom_form.save(user)

...profiles/models.py in save
super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

 ▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
__class__   

<class 'profiles.models.UserProfile'>

args    ()
kwargs  {}
self    Error in formatting: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: UserProfile has no user.
slug_name   'nome-sp-260221205510'
```

**Signals**

Using *signals* the error changed. I added it in **models.py**:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Error:

```
ValueError at /accounts/signup/
The 'foto' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Then I tried remove foto field, but the other error happens in another field:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
NOT NULL constraint failed: profiles_userprofile.data_nascimento
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your code looks quite good. The strange thing about the error is that durig template rendering, there shouldn't even exist any user object yet, and therefore user.profile shouldn't work at all. You would have to post more stack traces and the steps that lead to the error. Could it be that you access the page as an authenticated user (django-allauth should handle that, but maybe you have configured your urls.py to show you the page even if authenticated).

Comment: Thanks. I did some tests and added more details (I came back at the beginning, trying to use "ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS", so I go step by step).
Should I use a custom Signup View because of commit? (https://tech.serhatteker.com/post/2020-06/custom-signup-view-in-django-allauth/)

Comment: From your new error messages, it seems that whatever you did is going in the right direction. You seem to have declared fields in your model that might be optional on signup - you should allow them to be blank and/or null to avoid validation errors. Make sure to output all form errors in your template. - And also, please do not change your question anymore. This is a Q&A platform, and therefore, the question should stick to its original topic.

Comment: That's right, it was necessary to test field by field.
Thanks for letting me know. I was going to do that, but I got confused with the notification asking if instead of answering if I didn't prefer to edit or comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved! **No need** to use ***signals***. Here are the changes:

**forms.py**

I needed to use a single class:

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Nome")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Sobrenome")


    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

        fields = ('sexo', 'data_nascimento', 'foto', 'sobre_mim','telefone','paroquia',
                  'cidade','estado', 'cep', 'possui_filhos', 'facebook', 'instagram')

        CIDADES = []
        for i in cidadesReader:
            if i[1] not in CIDADES:
                CIDADES.append(i[1])
        widgets = {
            'cidade': floppyforms.widgets.Input(datalist=CIDADES, attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'}),
        }

    field_order = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',
               'sexo', 'data_nascimento', 'foto', 'sobre_mim','telefone','paroquia',
                'cidade','estado', 'cep', 'possui_filhos', 'facebook', 'instagram']


    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        profile, created = models.UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        profile.sexo = self.cleaned_data['sexo']
        profile.data_nascimento = self.cleaned_data['data_nascimento']


        def compressImage(foto):
            ... 
            return foto


        profile.foto = compressImage (self.cleaned_data['foto'])
        profile.sobre_mim = self.cleaned_data['sobre_mim']
        profile.telefone = self.cleaned_data['telefone']
        profile.paroquia = self.cleaned_data['paroquia']
        profile.cidade = self.cleaned_data['cidade']
        profile.estado = self.cleaned_data['estado']
        profile.cep = self.cleaned_data['cep']
        profile.possui_filhos = self.cleaned_data['possui_filhos']
        profile.facebook = self.cleaned_data['facebook']
        profile.instagram = self.cleaned_data['instagram']
        user.save()
        profile.save()
```

**Note:**

I was using a function to compress images, in **models.py**.
To correct the error

```
ValueError at /accounts/signup/
The 'foto' attribute has no file associated with it
```

I had to bring it to forms.py

**settings.py**

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'profiles.forms.SignupForm'

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True, related_name ='profile')


    SEXOS = (
        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Feminino'),
    )
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEXOS)
    ...
```

**Note:**

It was necessary to test field by field.
Sometimes there were some errors like `NOT NULL constraint failed` ou `no such table`.
The solutions to these problems:

- Add `null=True` in the field (temporarily)
- `makemigrations` and `migrate`
- Delete migrations

**signup.html**

Only `{{ form|crispy }}` is necessary (I could delete `{{ profile_form|crispy }}`)

```
<form novalidate method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Thank you for your help, @Risadinha.

Comment: Your solution is not recommendable, especially how you solved the "NOT NULL" problems. Adding  `null=True` will change the model to always allow null. Deleting the migrations and removing `null=True` later will just reintroduce the issue at a later, and even more inconvenient time. You need to decide whether these fields are required or not - if they are, you need to tell your users, if they are optional, then you should stick to it. If they are required at a later time, you might need custom validation in your form class, or you might even need two models.

Comment: In `SignupForm.signup` you are doing what regular Django model forms have built-in, already. If you need custom validation and assignments, you should override/implement the `clean_*` (per field validation+assignment), `SignupForm.clean` (all field validation+assignment) and `SignupForm.save` methods to follow with Django convention.

Comment: I agree. As it is a new project, I considered excluding migrations since it could have passed some incorrect value in some of them, as I saw in a forum (I ended up not mentioning), causing this kind of problem.
I still have a lot to learn about Django, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

The error `UserProfile has no user` is triggered in `UserProfile.save()`. You are calling this the first time in your view with `commit=False` and only afterwards are you setting the user:

```
# your code from the question

        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
```

I'm guessing that `UserProfile.save` reads the the `user` field to create the slug. You could either skip it if `commit=False`, or maybe it will already work if you change it like this:

```
profile_form.instance.user = user
profile.save()
```

Another common solution is, to provide the user when initializing the form, but then you would have to change your current view code quit a bit.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but my old view is no longer being used, correct?
I tried to do something similar to what you said using signals. The error has changed. I just added add this information in the topic. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @GustavodeAndrade I cannot tell you, if your view is still used. I did not even think of signals - did you try whether my suggested change improved anything?